# I can't loop an Object-Array with ember #each

Tags: ember.js, each, handlebars.js

```
<div class="nav-menu clearfix">
    <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
        {{#each MI in MB}}
            <li id=""><span>{{ MI.MText }}</span></li>
        {{else}}
            {{MB}}
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want loop the MB with each.

but it dose not work and return the MB is empty.

but I get this for else.

> [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object]

this is my route define

```
//application路由
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend(App.LazyLoadTemplate, {
    model : function() {
        return Ember.$.getJSON("/index/indexjson");
    }
});
```

and get a json data is

```
{
    'UIB':{...},
    'MB':[{...},{...},...,{...}]
}
```

My English is not well ,Thanks for help!

Comment: I did not define any thing without route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already found, your scope of your property was incorrect. Just to set the record straight, Ember-Handlebars will not iterate over an object like it will over an Array.  Additionally the else statement is totally legit, it will be triggered when the array being iterated across is empty (null/undefined/no elements)

```
{{#each item in model}}
   {{item}}
{{else}}
   No Items
{{/each}}
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/iWohUlE/1/edit

Comment: can I ask you one more question?how can I make sure the routeName that I have is in url currentRoutePath

Answer (score 0):

Edit as kingpin pointed out in his answer, this response is referencing the wrong version of handlebars.

Your misusing the block helper `each` in your template. Handlebars [`each`](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html) will work similarly with objects and arrays. In addition you had an `else` outside of an `if` block. Rewrite your template as follows:

```
<div class="nav-menu clearfix">
    <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
        {{#each MB}}
            <li id=""><span>{{ MText }}</span></li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/UK32S/1/)

Comment: Handlebars in Ember do not work similarly with objects and arrays, and the else is a valid syntax in the each helper.